# Apache URL rewrite to hide port numbers of web servers

Tags: apache-2.4, rewrite, apache2

I have an Ubuntu server running Gitea and Jenkins on ports 3000 and 4000 respectively. I want to be able to access them through a user friendly url like `http://myhost/gitea` and `http://myhost/jenkins`.

I tried using URL rewrite with the following rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/gitea http://myhost:3000/$1 [L,R]
```

However it only redirects me to `http://myhost:3000/` when I input `http://myhost/gitea` in the browser. How should I write my rule so that I can always see the app name instead of the ports? (ex: `http://myhost/gitea/login`, `http://myhost/gitea/explore/repos`, etc.)

Comment: The typical approach to achieve that is a reverse proxy configuration with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)  and `ProxyPass /gitea http://myhost:3000/`  and `ProxyPassReverse /gitea http://myhost:3000/`

Comment: Port numbers are a critical part of a URL. By convention, ports 80 and 443 are not displayed. If you want public connections on different port numbers than the connection **MUST** specify the port number. A better strategy is to implement a reverse proxy that listens on the standard ports 80/443 and forwards traffic to your application on whatever port number you want.